# how to display the content of session[:intented_url] using rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, view

I want to display the page that the user is logging in for ...

A user has to login before viewing pages. If not, then the user is redirected to login. It is at this point I want to display the name of the page they want to go to and view once logged in.

In the session controller, under the create def - I created the following instant variable:

```
@intended_url = Session::get('url.intended', url('/'));
```

and the view page contains the following:

```
<h4>Sign in to go back to <%= @intended_url %>.
```

Unfortunately, nothing is showing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store anything in the session, you must do so in a controller that has access to it. This means that setting the session takes place in a controller that is for a page. You do so by

session[:page_name = @intended_id

Then you can retrieve it with

display ------> session[:page_name]

Your problem can also be solved by instead calling the controller from the page.

Controller.controller_action

This displays your controllers action name which if you follow Ruby On Rails design will be your page name.

Comment: Hi cmw2379 - I'm fairly new at rails. Could you be so kind to give a written code example? Thanks!